# Crop video to frame

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, crop

I am trying to crop a video to a frame, which I scale to match the video's natural size scale. Is there a straight forward way to crop a video without dealing with all kinds of crazy transformations?

Is it possible to simply crop the frames in the `AVVideoComposition(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)` and then change the video composition `renderSize`?

If not, then what alternative is there?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you render your video. If you use `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` then set it's property -> `videoGravity` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`.

If you render from a `CVImageBufferRef`, `CVPixelBufferRef`or `CIImage`then I do this ->

```
        CGFloat w = self.videoPreviewView.drawableWidth;
        CGFloat h = self.videoPreviewView.drawableHeight;
        CGFloat previewAspect = w / h;
        CGRect drawRect = rect;
        drawRect.origin.y += (drawRect.size.height - drawRect.size.width / previewAspect) / 2.0;
        drawRect.size.height = drawRect.size.width / previewAspect;
```

And then render using `[self.ciContext drawImage:image inRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h) fromRect:drawRect];`

You can also use the method AVMakeRect (Swift3, forgot the Obj-C name) like this ->

```
let yourDrawableFrame:CGRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: video.size, insideRect: theViewToRenderIn.frame)
```

Hope that did answer your question else just clarify exactly what you want to achieve using what player/method.

Take care,

/Anders

Comment: I want to export this file cropped to the right dimensions. Where does this context come from? Can I set this as an AVVideoConpositionInruction? Does this take into account landscape videos and how they may be portrait but with some layer mask?

Comment: What you are asking for is complex and normally unnecessary since you easily crop and manipulate during playback, that is simple. If you crop the video and then want to save it as a new file you need to first decode, then crop then encode and then save as a new file. I would take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013109-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 That is a example on how to grab the pixels..

Comment: Then use the crop calculations I mentioned above. then encode for example -> https://github.com/manishganvir/iOS-h264Hw-Toolbox.

Why do you need to save a cropped video? why not just crop when playing?

Comment: I need to crop so that I can export the video to multiple types of devices and OSs. Can the videoRect do this simply for me?

Comment: Also this is not real time video processing. This is after the video has been fully captured.